# Inserting at the end of a list where the elements of the list are also lists

Tags: list, prolog

The program is required to do the following

Input:

```
encode_modified([a,a,a,a,b,c,c,a,a,d,e,e,e,e],X).
```

Output:

```
X = [[4,a],[1,b],[2,c],[2,a],[1,d],[4,e]]
```

I have written the following piece of code. It however gives me the list in reverse. I do not wish to manually reverse the list at the end. I believe I can get a solution  by modifying the insertIntoList() function. I'm however stuck at how to select a list as an element of the main list.

```
encode_modified([H|In],Out) :-
   encode(In,H,1,Out,[]).

encode([],Prev,Count,Temp1,Temp) :-
   createListFromPair(Count,Prev,Pair),
   insertIntoList(Pair,Temp,Temp1).
encode([H|In],Prev,Count,Out,Temp) :-
   (  H = Prev, Count1 is Count+1,
      encode(In,H,Count1,Out,Temp)
   ;
      createListFromPair(Count,Prev,Pair),
      insertIntoList(Pair,Temp,Temp1),
      encode(In,H,1,Out,Temp1),
      !
   ).

createListFromPair(H1,H2,[H1,H2]).

insertIntoList(H,Temp,[H|Temp]).
```

Comment: A cut at the end of an alternative branch is totally useless: that said, try to avoid cuts as far as possible. They are *required* (afaik) only to express negation, a fairly advanced topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code *can* behave as required, when simplified:

```
encode_modified([H|In],Out) :- encode(In,H,1,Out).

encode([],Prev,Count,[[Count,Prev]]).
encode([H|In],H,Count,Rest) :-
    Count1 is Count+1,
    encode(In,H,Count1,Rest).
encode([H|In],Prev,Count,[[Count,Prev]|Rest]) :-
    H \= Prev,
    encode(In,H,1,Rest).
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this without the auxiliary predicate. Your original naming (`createListFromPair` and `insertIntoList`) implies you're thinking *imperatively* as if coding in C. If you think *relationally*, you can have a predicate which works in either direction:

```
encoded([], []).
encoded([X], [[1,X]]).
encoded([X,Y|T], [[1,X]|R]) :-
    dif(X, Y),
    encoded([Y|T], R).
encoded([X,X|T], [[N,X]|R]) :-
    N #> 1,
    N #= N1 + 1,
    encoded([X|T], [[N1,X]|R]).
```

Here you'll get:

```
?- encoded([a, a, b, b, b], L).
L = [[2,a],[3,b]] ;
false.

?- encoded(L, [[2,a],[3,b]]).
L = [a, a, b, b, b] ;
false.

?-
```

For representation, a dash functor is a little more efficient and arguably clearer to read than a sublist of two elements:

```
encoded([], []).
encoded([X], [1-X]).
encoded([X,Y|T], [1-X|R]) :-
    dif(X, Y),
    encoded([Y|T], R).
encoded([X,X|T], [N-X|R]) :-
    N #> 1,
    N #= N1 + 1,
    encoded([X|T], [N1-X|R]).

?- encoded([a, a, b, b, b], L).
L = [2-a, 3-b] ;
false.
```